# How can I use shapefile or spatialite data for creating formatted PDF reports?

Tags: qgis, r, attribute-table, spatialite, reports

I am currently working on a landscape inventory in QGIS. I need to create a report based on the data we collected, as a pdf. The usual way in our group would be doing everything by hand. I figured out that using the atlas feature, I can create maps for each object, which I could use in a Word serial print. I can also export the dbf attribute table as a csv, and use it in the same word document as a data source, including paths to both photos of the objects and said maps. Additional information, like areas and lengths, would be a plus in some cases, but I can live without them. (I would probably populate the attribute table with this information for the reports.)

I wonder, however, how professionals would approach this. Any suggestions,as specific as possible? I  alsready pondered R and knitr, but I'm not sure if there is an easier way.

Comment: Use the html text box in composer to produce the text and save as single pdf from atlas

Comment: For automated reports, I always use R with knitr or sweave. Maybe it isn't the easiest way, but I think is the right one. You can loop throw QGIS outputs and csv's. (maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396755/using-loops-with-knitr-to-produce-multiple-pdf-reports-need-a-little-help-to) could be helpful)

Comment: I would use the atlas generator to create the entire report. Did you know... 1) Each atlas feature can have multiple pages. 2) You can add attribute tables and images to the print composer. 3) Using data-defined override settings, the attribute table and image filepath can be different for each atlas feature.

Comment: @aldo_tapia, did you only work with textfile and graphics output, or did you use the shapefiles and their dbf as as source? If so, I would be glad if you'd point me to some (pseudo)code.

Comment: @WilliamBligh I used shapefile as source. E.g. if `shp` is your shapefile, use `shp@data` instead of .csv file. You can use any field as iterator. I recommend you to use `xtable`package for table creation

Comment: @csk, I didn't realise that the composer could do that. I am looking into that, since my peers don't speak R and I need to hand the project over to them at some point.

Comment: @aldo_tapia, Hope I can manage to find the time. It's been a while since I worked with {maptools} and {rgdal}, and see above: my peers don't speak R.

Comment: @csk, thanks so much, the atlas composer is really more powerful than I thought.
I not yet managed to change image paths on by data defined override. I have the path information stored in a 'photo' field in the attribute table, in a project with relative paths. Any hint where I could find a how-to? Web search didn't help so far. Concatenating 
´@project_folder´  and  ´"foto1"´ field didn't work.

Comment: To troubleshoot your image path expression, try copying the expression into a text box, and see if it prints a correct file path. Often there will be problems with single quote mark when it should be double quote, or vice versa ( ' or " ).

Comment: Or post it as a new question on stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the atlas generator to create the entire report. Did you know...

1. Each atlas feature can have multiple pages.
2. You can add attribute tables and images to the print composer.
3. Using data-defined override settings, the attribute table and image filepath can be different for each atlas feature.

The atlas generator is a phenomenally useful and powerful tool. Check out these tutorials for more ways to use it:
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/atlas_generation.html

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/atlas_generation.html

http://gisgeography.com/how-to-create-qgis-atlas-mapbooks/